# VUE no carga contenido de la pagina al compilar

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

tengo un programa hecho en VUE que me funciona localmente pero deja de funcionar al compilar.

La idea es que dentor del archivo inicial de VUE App.vue me cargue contenido de otros archivos, en este caso del archivo Home.vue

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-app-bar app color="primary" dark>
      V.4.0
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
       2022  
    </v-app-bar>
    
    <v-main>
      <router-view/>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'App',
};
```

El index.js de las rutas

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: function () {
      return import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/Home.vue')
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/llistat',
    name: 'Llistat',
    component: function () {
      return import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/Llistat_feina.vue')
    }
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
</script>
```

I el **Home.vue**

```
<template>
    <v-container>
      <h1>Bienvenido</h1>
    <router-link to="/Llistat">1. Llistat</router-link><br>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
  

  export default {
    name: 'Home',

    components: {
    },
  }
</script>
```

Si lo ejecuto en local me sale bien. Carga el App.vue, busca la ruta y inserta el Home.vue

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si lo compilo y lo subo al server no carga el contenido de Home.vue, solo carga el codigo del App.vue

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea del que puede estar pasando? Gracias

Comment: En consola tenés algún error? Cuando decis que ejecutado localmente anda bien, pero subido al servidor no carga el contenido, a que te referís? Lo que ejecutas localmente lo haces por medio de "npm run serve" (o similar) o buildeas el proyecto y lo abrís localmente? Estoy seguro que al servidor subís la build, pero me quedó la duda de qué ejecutás localmente

Comment: En consola no da ningun error por eso no encuentro por donde puede venir el problema. Localmente lo hago con "npm run serve"

Comment: Y la build que subis al servidor, probaste abrirla localmente? (podes instalar el complemento LiveServer en vscode, click derecho al index.html -> Open with Live Server). A mi armar la build me daba ciertos problemas de rutas, no encontraba los archivos finales entonces tenia que ir al index.html y apuntarlos correctamente, pero no levantaba nada, a diferencia de lo que te pasa vos.

Comment: Desde LiveServe me pasa lo mismo, no carga el contenido

Comment: Lo unico que me dice eso es que el problema está en la build y no en el servidor. Yo primero buscaria por la consola (ya me dijiste que no hay error) y después analizaría con el inspector de chrome, si ese componente no está renderizandose en algun lugar pero con algun problema de css por el que no se está viendo. Descartado eso habria que ver como es tu archivo de configuración de vue, tal vez haya que configurar algunos parametros para que buildee bien, pero eso es ya mas avanzado respecto de lo que yo sé, ya no te puedo ayudar :/

Comment: Sacando el mode: 'history', del index.js de las rutas, funciona. Aunque la URL no queda como yo quiero